# Is there any way to pass an integer into a method chain?

Tags: ruby

Example:

```
7.cars.2.doors
```

I will add the `cars` method to Integer and it will return a `CarBuilding` object.

This `CarBuilding` object then needs to receive the message `2` which will do some processing and return itself.

Finally `doors` will be called on this CarBuilding object

Any kind of fancy Meta Programming able to do this?

Note: I don't want to pass parameters. Just use method chaining.

Comment: You can define a method, which is just an integer, but you can't invoke it nicely. You will have to do something like `7.cars.send('2').doors`.

Comment: @ndn this is a method named `"2"` (`String`’s instance,) not `2` (`Integer`.)

Comment: Yeah, I know I could do something like that but I am trying to do it through method chaining without params. It has now become more of a "is this even possible" thing for me... I am just not seeing how to do this but I feel like there must be some "secret passage" in Ruby... like getting the current line executing and transforming it or something. I just feel like there must be a way even if it is not elegant.

Comment: @mudasobwa well... method names don't really have a type in that sense, but sure, it's the string `'2'`.

Comment: If it were ever possible, floats implementation was indeed **broken**.

Comment: @slindsey3000 what about `7.cars._2.doors`?

Comment: @mudasobwa `send(:'2')` works as well, that doesn't make the method name a symbol.

Comment: @ndn no... it has to be in the pure form I have described

Comment: @slindsey3000 it's not possible then :/

Comment: @slindsey3000 why do you need this? Where would you have that kind of code?

Comment: @Stefan well, yes.

Comment: @stefan This started out as a thought.. say building a CarBuilding object ... now it is not super practical... but has become a thought experiment for me... just wondering is it possible... I just don't see ANY way to do it... It doesn't have to be pretty... I was even thinking if I could get the current executing line... maybe parse the line executing and transform it into something that can be interpreted.

Comment: @slindsey3000, actually you can have a code that edits itself, reloads itself and at the end, edits itself again (assuming the evaluation of `7.cars.2.doors` is delayed and doesn't straight out cause parse errors). But I don't think that counts as it would have to edit `7.cars.2.doors` to something valid.

Comment: What about `1.2`? Is that a float literal or `1.send(:'2')`? This is not going to work unless you patch Ruby's parser.

Comment: Oh snap... patch the parser... hmmm.. I'm thinking this goes against the spirit of what I am trying to do...

Comment: @ndn how do I go about implementing code that edits itself? Any links to this?

Comment: @slindsey3000, I don't have any links, but I imagine some combination of `File.read`, `File.write`, `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `Kernel#load`.

Comment: How can I modify this line of code during execution? Self reflection

Comment: The file should simply read itself, `gsub` its code, save itself and re`load` itself. At the end it also has to `gsub` and save itself so that the code is not permanently changed.

Comment: Actually it will not work as `7.cars.2.doors` causes parsing error even before the code starts execution. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

Using normal message sending syntax, the message must be a valid identifier. `2` is not a valid identifier, identifiers can't start with a digit. This is simply not syntactically legal.

It is possible to define a method named `2` using metaprogramming. Note, however, that this is the *name* `2` and not the `Integer` `2`. Obviously, it is not possible to invoke such a method using normal message sending syntax (nor is it possible to define it using normal method definition syntax).

```
class CarBuilding
  define_method(:'2') do
    CarBuildingWithDoors.new(2)
  end
end

7.cars.public_send(:'2').doors
```

Comment: Is there any self reflection on the line of code that I am executing that I can do? Perhaps transform it into something that will execute? For example: As you say my message is not a valid identifier... but once the 'cars' method is called, the program recognizes that a CarBuilding Object is being created and transforms the line of code into something else at runtime? ... but still allows this syntax... it is just edited at runtime. There is no practical reason for this... it is now just become... is this even possible....

Comment: @slindsey3000 the error occurs at the parser level.

Comment: No way to "break out" of the parser and fix the line of code once "cars" is called on 7?

Comment: @slindsey3000 well, you need some code to do that and the parser won't run code containing syntax errors. You could build your own parser / preprocessor and load the file containing your custom Ruby syntax yourself. But they cannot co-exits in the same file.

Comment: @slindsey3000: No. It's not valid Ruby. Period. If it's not Ruby, you can't run it with Ruby. I guess you are coming from a language like Katahdin where the syntax can be changed at runtime? Well, Ruby is not one of those languages, there are only about 5 languages or so that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Because names started with digit are not valid you can use underscore:

```
class CarBuilding
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    raise NoMethodError unless method =~ /\A_\d*\z/
    puts "do something with #{method[1..-1].to_i}"
    return self
  end
  def doors
    puts "doors"
  end
end

class Integer
  def cars
    return CarBuilding.new
  end
end

puts 7.cars._2.doors
```